# Xamarin Live Vizualization Error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

I did a simple GPS app in VS2017 Community but I opened it from VS2017 Preview. I rebuilt it.

After successful paring with VS2017 Preview with Xamarin Live Player, I selected Debug, iphone, Project.iOS(MyApp) and iphone Player.

After clicking iphone Player, I got this error:

Xamarin Live
Vizualization Error
You can now run your Project from Visual Studio.

But When I deployed this same App to my Android Phone, it is OK.

What cause the problem?

I would like to know :

1) Do I have to set up the iOS Project as the StartUp Project? But the result is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a 'Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException: Exception of type 'Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException' was thrown' ? If so, I am getting the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem.

Does your project contains references to PCL? If so , then we are tend to get this error.

From the below comment from James Montemagno 2017-05-30 18:07:53 UTC @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56259

"The current **iOS build supported Shared projects**, and the next version has the fix for PCL projects."

Comment: Is there any new version fixing this bug? Visual Studio 15.4. is released now and I still get this bug...

Comment: Got the bug today